# What is the static keyword for in annotation class "public static @interface"?

Tags: java, static, annotations

I found a strange annotation:

```
public static @interface WebResult { }
```

Why is `static` there? How do they compile it? My IDE does not allow such modifier there!

The class this is contained in is `javax.jws.WebResult`.

Comment: found answer. Intelij Idea Decompiler Lies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's valid (but not required) when it's nested inside another class:

```
public class Foo {   
    public static @interface Bar {
    }    
}
```

From the Java language specification [section 8.5.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.5.2):

> Member interfaces are always implicitly static. It is permitted but not required for the declaration of a member interface to explicitly list the static modifier.

If you've seen it on a top-level class, please show *where* you've found it like that.

Comment: With static it's should raise a CTE when used on the top level class.